# What is the RegEx to test for a compliant FATCA Global Intermediary Identification Number (GIIN)?

Tags: regex, ruby

[This is the spec](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-utl/giin_composition.pdf) for the FATCA GIIN.

19 digits, alphanumeric and only uppercase, in 4 groups, each separated by a compulsory dot/period:

XXXXXX.XXXXX.XX.XXX

First two groups are alphanumeric uppercase, but never include uppercase O.

3rd group seems to only allow strict combination of 2 uppercase letters:

```
LE|SL|ME|BR|SP
```

4th group is only digits.

I have this so far, but am stuck on how to add that 'never allow O' rule:

```
[A-Z0-9]){6}\.[A-Z0-9]){5}\.(LE|SL|ME|BR|SP)\.\d{3}
```

So how can I restrict those first 2 groups to now allow the O?

NOTE - this is for **Ruby**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use [character class intersection](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclassintersect.html) and - to match the entire string - anchors:

```
/\A[A-Z0-9&&[^O]]{6}\.[A-Z0-9&&[^O]]{5}\.(?:LE|SL|ME|BR|SP)\.\d{3}\z/
```

To match as whole word only use word boundaries, `\b`, instead of anchors:

```
/\b[A-Z0-9&&[^O]]{6}\.[A-Z0-9&&[^O]]{5}\.(?:LE|SL|ME|BR|SP)\.\d{3}\b/
```

See the [Rubular demo](https://rubular.com/r/RIf7a35bHnuXgk).

**Details**

- `\A` - start of string
- `[A-Z0-9&&[^O]]{6}` - 6 uppercase letters or digits but not `O`
- `\.` - dot
- `[A-Z0-9&&[^O]]{5}` - 5 uppercase letters or digits but not `O`
- `\.` - dot
- `(?:LE|SL|ME|BR|SP)` - `LE`, `SL`, `ME`, `BR` or `SP`
- `\.` - dot
- `\d{3}` - any three digits
- `\z` - end of string

Comment: `[A-NP-Z\d]` looks ...ahem visually less impairing :)

Comment: Thanks for all the details, but I think overall the regex of @thefourthbird is easier to understand at first read. But still very worthy of a plus one :) Thanks, I learned a lot from your answer.

Comment: @rmcsharry You may use any workarounds as far as they are working the same. But this is the solution to the "how to exclude some specific chars from a more generic character class" problem in Ruby. I did not create this functionality, note in .NET it might look less "impairing" - `[A-Z0-9-[O]]`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That is a good point. Based on a strict intepretation of what I asked (which as you say was worded on 'how to exclude") then your answer (and in fact even my own answer too - although harder to grok) is correct. So marking yours as correct now.

Answer (score 1):

The format of the current pattern is not correct, there are unclosed groups.

To omit the `O` you could use `[A-NP-Z]`

If you don't need the groups you could use:

```
\b[A-NP-Z0-9]{6}\.[A-NP-Z0-9]{5}\.(?:LE|SL|ME|BR|SP)\.\d{3}\b
```

**Explanation**

- `\b` Word boundary
- `[A-NP-Z0-9]{6}` Match 6 times A-Z without O
- `\.` Match `.`
- `[A-NP-Z0-9]{5}` Match 5 times A-Z0-9 without O
- `\.` Match `.`
- `(?:LE|SL|ME|BR|SP)` Match any of the lister
- `\.` Match `.`
- `\d{3}` Match 3 digits
- `\b` Match word boundary

[Regex demo](https://rubular.com/r/zP4xJbqEyULGPG)

You could add word boundaries `\b` around the pattern to prevent the start and end being part of a larger word. Or you could add `\A` and `\z` anchors to match the start and the end of the string.

Comment: Thanks for all your input, I learned a lot from this, but based on how I worded the question, wiktor's answer is more correct to what I asked. Sorry!

Comment: @rmcsharry That is no problem at all. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I needed something called a negative look-ahead:

```
(?:(?![O])
```

which basically says 'except O' (in the group that follows, hence 'look-ahead').

So the final solution is this (I think, not sure but seems to work):

```
(?:(?![O])[A-Z0-9]){6}\.(?:(?![O])[A-Z0-9]){5}\.(?:LE|SL|ME|BR|SP)\.\d{3}
```

Comment: What would be wrong with way more simple `[A-NP-Z0-9]`?!

Comment: Nothing would be wrong - I'm not a RegEx expert and totally agree that simpler is better when it comes to RegEx. It is obvious now I see it that you can do that. Doh!